# Calculate the angles in the triangles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

[image]
Without giving any angles, show should I solve this question? Any ideas or any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you given any more information?

Comment: Nope. That's the problem.

Comment: Hint: $\;\theta = (\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha)+(\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta)$

Comment: @dxiv how so?  If you keep everything in the figure the same but shorten the line for angle beta to the point of the circle clockwise of angle beta, we will make the angle beta smaller while keeping theta and alpha exactly the same.

Comment: @fleablood No, angle $\beta$ will stay the same because its complementary will subtend the same constant arc.

Comment: @fleablood You don't need any additional condition. Angle $\theta$ is the half-sum of the two arcs the respective chords intercept on the circle. The arc on the left is subtended by the inscribed angle which is the complement of $\alpha$, the arc on the right by the complement of $\beta$, whence my previous hint.

Comment: Yeah, foolish of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$1)$ Once $\angle EIC =90°$ then $\angle ECD =90°-\alpha \to \text{arc}(ED)=2(90°-\alpha)$;

$2)$ Once $\angle HJG =90°$ then $\angle HGF = 90°-\beta \to \text{arc}(FH)=2(90°-\beta)$;

but

$$\theta=\frac{\text{arc}(ED)+\text{arc}(FH)}{2}=\frac{2(90°-\alpha)+2(90°-\beta)}{2}\to \alpha+\beta+\theta=180°$$

Comment: $2\theta = arc(ED) + arc(FH)$. Please explain.Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSzilas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TB7-uZWnS9g